# Putting a value to ostream

Tags: c++, ostream

I have this code below which parses a for statement, but I am not sure how to put any value into the `ostream` when calling the method `write(...)`. What can I do? (e.g `write("for (........."))`

```
#include <ostream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//I cut out the declaration bit here

typedef const string type;

private:
type *initializer;
type *condition;
type *increment;
type *body;

public:
void write(ostream& stream) const {
      stream
        << "for ("
        << *initializer << "; "
        << *condition << "; "
        << *increment << ")\n{\n"
        << *body
        << "}";
}
```

Comment: Typically you write an actual parser to do this job. C++ is far too complex to parse like this (whatever "this" is)

Comment: Do you mean, what sort of thing should you pass to `write`? An output stream, like `std::cout` (to write to the console), an open `ofstream` (to write to a file), or an `ostringstream` (to write to a string). If you're asking something else, please clarify.

Comment: The only parameter your `write()` function takes is the stream, it gets everything else from the member variables of the object.

Comment: @Mike Seymour - Would an ifstream work?

Comment: @user2976089 no, because you're taking an `ostream` and `ifstream` is an `istream`

Comment: @user2976089: No, that's for reading from a file. This function is intended to write the data to some kind of output.

Comment: How can you have `private:` and `public:` declarations outside of a class declaration?

Comment: Seems more like some snippets from your code pasted together... What was your problem? Does your *actual* code compile? What output do you get? And what did you expect?

Comment: Please post a more complete impression of your code (at least tell us what the class is), and try to give an example to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Axel - I get an error using the ostream on the second line (<<) saying ` IntelliSense: no operator "<<" matches these operands
            operand types are: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`

Comment: @user2976089: That's only part of an error message.

Comment: psychic debugging, activate! `#include <string>`

Comment: BTW any reason to store pointer to string instead of string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you try to learn using `ostream` as an input in a function. But it seems that you mixing things that how to use `class`s and `method`s.
Maybe this is no avail but i can give you a little snippet to give you some opinion.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

typedef const string type;

type *init;
type *cond;
type *incr;
type *body;


void write(ostream& stream) {
      stream
        << "for ("
        << *init << "; "
        << *cond << "; "
        << *incr << ")\n{\n"
        << *body
        << "\n}";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    const string ini = "int i = 0";
    const string con = "i < 10";
    const string inc = "i++";
    const string bod = "cout << i << endl;";

    init = &ini;
    cond = &con;
    incr = &inc;
    body = &bod;

    write(cout);

    return 0;
}
```

Try this code, examine and read more for more details.

Comment: How does the function `write(cout)` work, when nothing has been outputted?

Comment: nothing has been outputted? It actually outputs a for loop block. Try to add `cin>>argc;` before the return statement.